# how to get the distinct line in the output?

Tags: shell

in my terminal:

```
ps  aux|awk '{print $1}'
USER
root
root
root
root
statd
root
root
root
101
daemon
avahi
avahi
103
rtkit
debian
debian
debian
```

i want to get the output is
USER
root
statd
101
daemon
avahi
103
rtkit
debian

how to write the shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pipe the command output through sort and then uniq

```
ps  aux|awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq
```

It gets a little more complicated if you need the list in a specific order.

Comment: You can use `sort -u` instead of running the output through `uniq` afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
ps  aux | awk '!a[$1]++{print $1}'
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of `awk '{print $1}'` use below:

```
awk '{a[$1];next}END{for(i in a )print i}'
```